# Not counting all the coins

Tags: c++, double, modulo

I'm trying to create a simple change sorter program, everything is functioning properly expect for the part that's suppose to detect quarters.

Example of current output:

```
The amount you entered is: 52.50

You have this many Fifty dollars: 1 

You have this many Ten dollars: 0

You have this many One: 2

You have this many Quarters: 0
```

Desired output:

```
The amount you entered is: 52.50

You have this many Fifty dollars: 1 

You have this many Ten dollars: 0

You have this many One: 2

You have this many Quarters: 2
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int FIFTY = 50;
const int TEN = 10;
const int ONE = 1;
const double QUARTER = 0.25;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int change;

    cout << "Enter the amount of money in your wallet: ";
    cin >> change;
    cout << endl;


    cout << "The amount you entered is: " << change << endl;
    cout << "The number of Fifty dollars to be returned is: " << change / FIFTY << endl;
    change = change % FIFTY;

    //
    cout << "The number of Ten dollars to be returned is: " << change / TEN << endl;
    change = change % TEN;

    //
    cout << "The number of One dollars to be returned is: " << change / ONE << endl;
    change = change % ONE;

    //
    cout << "The number of Quarters to be returned is: " << change / QUARTER << endl;
    change = change % QUARTER;

    return 0;
}
```

The 2 errors I'm getting are:

```
Error   1   error C2297: '%' : illegal, right operand has type 'double' 

Error2  IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you use cents as your units rather than dollars.  That way you won't have to deal with non-integer types.

Comment: If you convert everything to cents, you can avoid this issue.

Comment: To clarify further, `FIFTY`, `TEN` and `ONE` are all integers, but `QUARTERS` is `double` (0.25).  It doesn't make sense to try to take the remainder when dividing by a floating point value.

Comment: `change = change % QUARTER;` isn't valid because QUARTER is 0.25 which is not integral.  You could just say `change -= QUARTER * (change / QUARTER);`.  Note that when using float point types (here `double`), there's often tiny rounding errors, so `change` may not be exactly 0 afterwards.

Comment: Is there a better way to just create a program like this then? It has to be dollars and just one coin value, that being the quarters. I'll start from scratch since the way seems to bit the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Your `change` variable is an `int` type, so it won't store `52.50` at all.

It will read the `52` then stop.

On top of that, you can't use floating point values in the `%` operator.

I would suggest *reading* the value as a double, multiplying it by a hundred, perhaps adding a small delta (like `0.001`) so as to avoid potential floating point precision problems, then placing that into an `int`. In other words, make it an integral number of cents.

Then use the `int` for doing the calculations.